# WebStorm theme replica of VSCode theme using dark_vs.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, webstorm

I like Visual Studio theme a lot. Its far better than any theme I have seen. I was curious to know if anyone has converted this `dark_vs.json` theme to its WebStorm equivalent. If so, can someone help me with it?

Also, is there a specific way to convert the json into an icls format for WebStorm to import it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please check https://github.com/lenny1882/vscode-dark-plus-webstorm (editor color scheme). I'd also suggest looking at [Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui)  plugin (UI theme + code color schemes) - it can be installed via **Settings | Plugins**, **Browse repositories...**

Comment: I did check it.. its a perfect match.! thanks!

Comment: When you install the Material Theme plug-in, it may or may not the editor colors. In my case the theme was applied to the IDE except the editor. I had to manually set the Editor Colors in the Settings > Editor > Color Scheme.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/mkubdev/material-vscode-jetbrains to get the colorScheme from lenny1882 and a .xml contained the Dark+ theme for the plugin Material UI.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer! Very helpful!

Comment: Download or clone the repo. 

Webstrom > preferences > Color Scheme. Import scheme > vscode_dark+_webstorm.icls